# how can I delete a word backword from the cursor position in xshell

Tags: shell, shortcut, xshell

I can do that almost in any ssh client, but xshell cant. Is there any way to enable `alt+backspace` to do that?

Comment: From my understanding, [xshell](https://xshell.en.softonic.com/) is a terminal emulatior. Getting keys to work in a terminal emulator is not related to programming. May I suggest that you post this in [superuser](https://superuser.com/) instead?

Comment: of course @user1934428, [question in superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1615353/how-can-i-delete-a-word-backword-from-the-cursor-position-in-xshell)